# SQL: How to Alter a Database WHEN Something is Deleted?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I have the following question on my assignment that I've been stuck on for a while now:

when employee S is deleted

i. set FKs in Employee and Department to null

ii. delete referenced rows in Works_On and Dependent

I've been thinking that I should use a CASE statement for this, but I'm not sure how I should go about structuring the SQL. I am using Postgresql.

The following link is a screenshot of my database structure:
http://puu.sh/rMLjp/886c6e8a5b.png

Comment: I think you would need to show us table structure (and better yet some data) to get a detailed answer, but off the top of my head `ON DELETE CASCADE` sounds like something you might want to be doing here.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I don't use CASE here.

I'm not sure if this is allowed, but here is a screenshot of my database structure with the applicable tables.

http://puu.sh/rMLjp/886c6e8a5b.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [PostgreSQL manual on FOREIGN KEY constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)?

> Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options. RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.) CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well.
>
> **There are two other options: SET NULL and SET DEFAULT. These cause the referencing column(s) in the referencing row(s) to be set to nulls** or their default values, respectively, when the referenced row is deleted.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE works_on (
    essn ... REFERENCES employee(ssn) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    pno ...,
    hours ...
);
```

I can't guess at the data types for your columns from your screenshot. But the excerpt and link to the manual, and that partial code example, should give you what you need to know.

Comment: Thank you! Reading up on that made it clear to me what I needed to do.